# Automatic Copy of an Item to another list

Tags: list, library, item

I want to create a list which have a combo box. For example if the combo box value was "List 1"  then a copy of this item will send to list 1. if the combo box value was "list 2" then the copy will send to list 2.
How is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would do is create a workflow inside of SharePoint Designer. Use if and then statements for your combobox values and select a create list item action to the relevant list and populate the values. The workflows in SharePoint Designer are powerful and gives you all these capabilities plus more.